How to setup Snowflake ODBC driver
I am trying to setup the Snowflake ODBC driver and get the following error when I test the connection:
[Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL *** failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=404 Verify that the hostnames and portnumbers in SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST are added to your firewall's allowed list. To further troubleshoot reference the following article : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/client-connectivity-troubleshooting/error-messages#odbc-errors.

Hi - so what don’t you understand about the error message? What happened when you worked through the documentation that the error message referenced?
